# Pygame's mouse.get_rel() returns values when mouse isn't moving

Tags: python, pygame, mouse

In my program pygame.mouse.get_rel() as well as event.rel return tuples such as (0, -1) or any other of (1,0), (0,1), (1,1) etc. even when mouse is not moving.
When i move the mouse i get correct values, but when i stop it again returns one of these tuples (returns one of them until i move the mouse and when i stop moving, it starts to return other tuple randomly and repeats until next mouse move).
It makes my game unable to play.
Here is the important part of the code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
pygame.event.set_grab(True)

game_exit = False

while not game_exit:
    mouse_move = (0,0)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_exit = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            print(event.rel) #returns (0, -1)
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        game_exit = True

    print(pygame.mouse.get_rel()) #returns (0, -1)

pygame.quit()
```

EDIT: I noticed that removing either

```
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
```

or

```
pygame.event.set_grab(True)
```

solves the problem, but both methods are needed.

Comment: That's odd. It works correctly for me (prints `(0, 0)` when the mouse isn't moving).

Comment: Which operating system, Python and pygame version do you use?

Comment: Windows 8, Python 3.6 and the built - in pygame, not sure how to check it edit: 1.9.3 says pygame.version.ver

Comment: `pygame.ver` returns the version. I'm not sure how we could find the cause of this error. Maybe something is wrong with the mouse or it's a bug in pygame.

Comment: it says version 1.9.3

Comment: Could you try moving your mouse few times? it happens in like 40% of time

Comment: Also, moving my mouse to the corners of my window it returns these values more often

Comment: I've run the program several times and don't see any errors.

Comment: It can't be problem with mouse as removing mentioned lines solves the problem (or actually does not)

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what happens if we calculate the mouse position and offset with `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` and vectors. Check out if this program produces the same error:

```
import pygame
from pygame.math import Vector2

pygame.init()
game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
pygame.event.set_grab(True)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
game_exit = False

previous_pos = Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

while not game_exit:
    mouse_move = (0,0)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_exit = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                game_exit = True

    current_pos = Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
    print(current_pos-previous_pos)
    previous_pos = current_pos
    clock.tick(3)  # 3 frames per second.

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't :( I noticed that my cursor keeps moving in the way of last mouse move. For example if i move my mouse to bottom right corner it usually starts to return (1,1) when i stop the mouse. Also my pygame.mouse.get_pos() changes as if i moved the mouse so now i understand that there is a problem with my equipment

Comment: Do you also have trouble with the mouse in other applications?

Comment: Absolutely not. No trouble with fullscreen too and as i said - without one of these methods